# Error while trying to join peer to channel in fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to build a fabric network with two channels. One peer is able to join the channel but while trying to join  the second peer to channel getting following error:

**Error: genesis block file not found open mychannel.block: no such file or directory**

this is my code used for channel creation and joining peers:

Creating channel:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" peer0.org2.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
```

Joining peers:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" peer0.org2.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

Please correct if something is wrong.

Comment: Can you please share the solution if you have resolved the same!

Answer (score 3):

i run in the same situation and find a solution.
Since the **mychannel.block** is known only to **peer0.org2.example.com** container, all the joins have to be done from there.
For the second peer you can issue:

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e "peer0.org1.example.com:7051" peer0.org2.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block

M

Comment: Could you clarify what `-e "peer0.org1.example.com:7051"` means in the command line?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that **mychannel.block** is only available within the **peer0.org2.example.com** container (since that is the container where you ran the channel create command).  The **peer0.org1.example.com** container does not have access to **mychannel.block** and that's why you get the error.

What you will need to do is to actually have to do is mount a shared volume for both containers and make sure that you when you run channel create that **mychannel.block** is output in the shared volume

Comment: How can i mount a shared volume for 2 containers? I am new to fabric. thanks.

Comment: @Saya22K that is not related to Fabric. It is a docker question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the scenario was slightly different: I had two peers (`peer0` and `peer1`) in one org (`org1`). I used the following commands to join them to the same channel, and it works:

```
//Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e 
"CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" 
peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block

//Join peer1.org1.example.com to the channel.

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e 
"CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051" peer0.org1.example.com peer 
channel join -b mychannel.block
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your docker-compose.yaml file to see how you're mapping volumes in there

in the definitions of the two peers, ensure there is a common mapped volume, for example in peer0 you may have something like this;

```
    volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - ./crypto-config/peers/peer0/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
    - ./crypto-config/users/user0/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
```

and in your peer1 you may have;

```
    volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - ./crypto-config/peers/peer1/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
    - ./crypto-config/users/user1/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
```

You can see here there are two shared volume mappings, the first two in each definition point to the sample place.

So to be clear, the volume mapping is defined as follows:

```
[path on local machine]:[path to map in docker image]
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to mychannel.block was not found in peer0.org1.example.com
You can copy mychannel.block from peer0.org2.example.com to peer0.org1.example.com

try these commands

```
docker cp peer0.org2.example.com:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/mychannel.block mychannel.block


docker cp mychannel.block peer0.org1.example.com:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/

sudo rm mychannel.block
```

Now try rejoining peer0.org1.example.com to mychannel.